# Using ImportXML to extract view counts of urls from a tiktok account

Tags: tiktok

So I saw a previous question here that was aiming for the same goal as mine and they did find an answer and made it work however now the formula doesnt seem to work anymore. It might be because tiktok changed or whatever but if anyone can help will be greatly appreciated.

Current code:
=IMPORTXML([https://www.tiktok.com/@estrellawilliams8,"//a[contains(@href,'https://www.tiktok.com/@estrellawilliams8/video/7057587198505454895')]//strong[@data-e2e='video-views']"](https://www.tiktok.com/@estrellawilliams8,%22//a%5Bcontains(@href,%27https://www.tiktok.com/@estrellawilliams8/video/7057587198505454895%27)%5D//strong%5B@data-e2e=%27video-views%27%5D%22))

It comes up as imported content is empty.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xT2mm.jpg)

Been trying the code above so far.

Want to see the raw view count of the video show as a result.